# Laravel dynamic routes issue

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I try do build a ecommerce-like routing with nested categories and single items in Laravel, which works pretty good but with on big exception.

This is the important part of my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@home')->name('Home');
Route::get('/{category}', 'PageController@show')->where('category', '.+')->name('Category');
Route::get('/{slug}/{item_id?}', 'ItemController@show')->name('Item');
```

As you can see, the logic for categories and items is separated in two different controllers.

The category thing works pretty well with these url patterns like `www.page.com/category` or `www.page.com/category/subcategory` or even `www.page.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory`.

But when I try to call the items with `www.page.com/item-slug` or `www.page.com/item-slug/12345`, the script always uses the category route.

In my item model I also did overwrite the route key name:

```
...
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

...but with no success.

Hope, you can help me out or you once have had a similar issue.

Comment: How many categories do you have? If you've a very limited number of categories you can use regex pattern to match categories.

Comment: It depends on each category, from 1 to 5 child categories. But the category routing is fine. I just wonder why the item routing uses the category pattern.

Comment: Because your categories regexp pattern .+ matches any combination of characters so who tells the router that it should route to an item instead of a category?

Answer (score 0):

Its real bad approach you are using right now. You better use prefix for every route for many reasons (you can google it). For example,

```
 Route::get('/', 'PageController@home')->name('Home');
 Route::get('/categoryPrefix/{category}', 'PageController@show')>where('category', '.+')->name('Category');
 Route::get('/itmPrefix/{slug}/{item_id?}', 'ItemController@show')->name('Item');
```

And access these routes with the defined prefix.

Comment: Well, I don't think so. Plenty of successful systems use this approach.

Comment: Yeah with its own limitations :)

Comment: And never take an argument like "a lot of systems use it so i am gonna use it." It's gonna affect your project in the long run.

Comment: You are right and it might be a solution but not in my case.